# How to determine subnet IPv4 CIDR address in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip-address, amazon-vpc, subnet, vpc

How to determine subnet IPv4 CIDR address in AWS. Suppose my VPC CIDR block is 172.31.0.0/16 and I want to create a subnet with 172.31.1.0/16 but it says " *** is not within the range of ****/*. Please explain me how to determine CIDR?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`172.31.0.0/16` represents these IP ranges:

```
CIDR Range      172.31.0.0/16
Netmask         255.255.0.0
Wildcard Bits   0.0.255.255
First IP        172.31.0.0
Last IP         172.31.255.255
Total Host      65536
```

`172.31.1.0/16` represents the same IP range because of the `/16` subnet mask which would be like `172.31.1.0/255.255.0.0`:

```
CIDR Range      172.31.1.0/16
Netmask         255.255.0.0
Wildcard Bits   0.0.255.255
First IP        172.31.0.0
Last IP         172.31.255.255
Total Host      65536
```

Therefore it's not a subset of `172.31.0.0/16`.

Perhaps you'd be comfortable with 256 IPs per subnet? In which case you could use `172.31.1.0/24` which would allow the IP range of `172.31.1.0` - `172.31.1.255`:

```
CIDR Range      172.31.1.0/24
Netmask         255.255.255.0
Wildcard Bits   0.0.0.255
First IP        172.31.1.0
Last IP         172.31.1.255
Total Host      256
```

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing.