# Verify that boto3 in EC2 is using VPC endpoint to connect to S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

How can I verify that `boto3.client('s3')` in EC2 is using VPC endpoint?

In AWS, I have a created VPC Endpoint (service=s3, type=gateway). From what I understand, boto automagically selects its `client(endpoint_url)`. I am ingesting terabytes of data, so I don't want to get charged egress fees when writing from EC2 to S3.

#### Desktop

```py
>>> import boto3
>>> conn = boto3.client('s3')
>>> conn._endpoint

"s3(https://s3.amazonaws.com)"
```

#### AWS Batch Job - Fargate within VPC

I want more information here. Is it pointed to my VPC Endpoint ID/ARN?

```py
>>> import boto3
>>> conn = boto3.client('s3')
>>> conn._endpoint

"s3(https://s3.amazonaws.com)"
```

---

Here, boto3 acknowledges the existence of my VPC Endpoint

```py
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> import boto3

>>> conn = boto3.client('ec2')    #<-- note 'ec2' not 's3'
>>> resp = conn.c.describe_vpc_endpoints()
>>> pprint(resp['VpcEndpoints'])
```

Comment: Also, can I enforce the use of a specific VPC Endpoint id/arn rather than depending on automagic?

Comment: Haven't double-checked this, so please verify. There are 2 types of VPC Endpoint for S3. If you're using an Interface Endpoint then use DNS to resolve the S3 endpoint (s3.amazonaws.com). It should yield a private IP inside the VPC. If you're using a Gateway Endpoint then check the route table for an S3 prefix list entry that targets the VPC Endpoint. Suspect you can modify the routing for the Gateway Endpoint option to target a specific VPC-E.

Comment: via s3 logging https://serverfault.com/a/894754/459966

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I can think of is to use [bucket policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/vpc-endpoints-s3.html#bucket-policies-s3). You can restrict bucket access to a specific endpoint. If your requests still work after the bucket policy is applied, then it means your requests are going through the VPC endpoint.

#### Example: Restrict access to a specific endpoint

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Allow-access-to-specific-VPCE",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": ["s3:PutObject", "s3:GetObject", "s3:DeleteObject"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name",
                   "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/*"],
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotEquals": {
          "aws:sourceVpce": "vpce-1a2b3c4d"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: good idea. can't confirm yet. my job can't fetch ecr container after putting that policy in place for my bucket/vpce combo.

Answer (score 0):

## S3 Logs

*Another indirect solution without use of boto*

S3 logs contain the IP address of the requester. The IP I observed matches the `172.31.0.0/16` CIDR of my VPC as opposed to a public IP, so I conclude that my endpoint/gateway is working.

---

#### Process

- Created a new bucket to store logs
- In my original bucket that I want to monitor: Properties > Server Access  Logging

  - Enable
  - Point to newly created log bucket
- Wait 45 min for logs to appear

---

#### Supplemental Info

- [Enable s3 logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/enable-server-access-logging.html)
- [Format of logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/LogFormat.html)
- [CIDR range](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41893068/5739514)